# Laravel 5.6 - 404 though route defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Trying to access admin/users/multidel and its giving me a 404 error

Chrome console.log:

```
DELETE http://****.test/admin/users/multidel 404 (Not Found)
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.home');;

    Route::delete('admin/users/multidel', 'AdminUsersController@multiDel')->name('users.multidel');
    Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
});
```

php artisan route:list

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                     | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                   | admin.home       | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@index                             | web,admin    |
|        | POST      | admin/users             | users.store      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@store                        | web,admin    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users             | users.index      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@index                        | web,admin    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/create      | users.create     | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@create                       | web,admin    |
|        | DELETE    | admin/users/multidel    | users.multidel   | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@multiDel                     | web,admin    |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/users/{user}      | users.update     | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@update                       | web,admin    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/{user}      | users.show       | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@show                         | web,admin    |
|        | DELETE    | admin/users/{user}      | users.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@destroy                      | web,admin    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/{user}/edit | users.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@edit                         | web,admin    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                    | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                   | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | login                   |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | logout                  | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST      | password/email          | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | password/reset          |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset          | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}  | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | register                |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I've defined it in web.php, and its above the resource (users) so should take precedence over any other route in the 'user' resource.
What am I missing?

//edit

The view code:

```
                                            <li class="m-nav__item">
                                                <a href="{{route('users.multidel')}}" data-method="delete" class="m-nav__link" id="multi-delete">
                                                    <i class="m-nav__link-icon la la-trash-o"></i>
                                                    <span class="m-nav__link-text">
                                                        Multi-Delete
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
```

and the js that drives it:

```
        $("#multi-delete").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);

            var selected_ids = [];
            var selected_hids = "";
            $("tbody .m-checkable:checked").each(function() {
                selected_ids.push($(this).val());
                selected_hids += $("#data-row-"+$(this).val()).find("a.jquery-postback").data('hid')+"<br>";
            });

            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",html: "Are you sure you want to delete <strong>multiple records</strong>?<br>The following will be deleted:<br>"+selected_hids+"<br>You won't be able to revert this action once taken!",type: "warning",showCancelButton: true,confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete all records!"
            }).then(function(ev) {
                if (ev.value) {
                    $.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});

                    $.post({
                        type: $this.data('method'),
                        url: $this.attr('href'),
                        data: selected_ids,
                    }).done(function (result) {
                        console.log($result);
                        if (result.status == 1) {
                            bootstrapNotify('success', 'Deleted Successfully', 'Your records "' + $this.data('hid') + '" was deleted successfully.');
                            $('#records-table').DataTable().row("#data-row-" + result.id).remove().draw();
                        }
                        else {
                            bootstrapNotify('danger', 'Delete Failed', 'Your record "' + $this.data('hid') + '" was <strong>not</strong> deleted successfully.');
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        });
```

the controller code:

```
public function multiDel($request)
{
    $users = User::findOrFail($request->selected_hids);

    $result = 1;
/*
    foreach ($users as $user){
        if (!$user->delete() && $result == 1)
            $result = 0;
    }
*/
    foreach ($users as $user){
        $result += $user->email;
    }
    return response()->json($result);
}
```

Comment: The other admin/users resource endpoints works as expected?

Comment: Yes they do work...

Comment: `admin/users/multidel` is a `DELETE` method and can only be accessed  if you pass a form request with an input of `_method` with the value of `delete`. That or change the route from  `Route::delete()` to `Route::get()`.

Comment: I'm passing the method as delete: "type: $this.data('method'), " - works fine with my single entity destroy method. As per my console.log details above, the DELETE prefix indicates the right method is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Add it after the Resource..

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.home');;

    Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
    Route::delete('admin/users/multidel', 'AdminUsersController@multiDel')->name('users.multidel');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the delete route back above the resource route and obviously changed something else along the way because now its no longer a 404 error but a 500 error.

```
"message": "Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminUsersController::multiDel(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected",
```

Which is an entirely different issue altogether now so I consider the original query resolved.
I think what I changed was the function definition:

```
public function multiDel($request)
```

It was ...multiDel(Request $request) at a stage - I put it back to that and saw that then the 404 came back. Further investigation showed:

```
message": "No query results for model [App\\User].",
```

Which indicates then there was something wrong with the $request data. Strange that it throws a 404 when the page is loading but has an error on it.
Hope this helps someone in the future...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, mine was fixed by clearing route cache `php artisan route:clear`

~Regards